# Backbone/Node CORS : Options 200 OK, POST not working (Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: node.js, post, backbone.js, express, cors

I'm facing the current problem which seems pretty strange to me. I'm using backbone on the front to handle my app and Node/Express on the back.

The OPTIONS request results in an 200 OK (I added a middleware on my node to allow CORS request) but the POST request ain't firing. Also the OPTIONS is 200 but it's still raising me an error in my console...

I've taken some screenshots :

Options Request:
[image: OPTIONS OK]

Post Request:
[image: POST ERROR]

Errors in the console
[image: errors]

THanks by advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin authorizes for `http://localhost` while the request is to `http://localhost:5000`
You need to allow for that too.

Comment: Yes the protocol, domain and port must match.